# Is there a way to check if a particular jdk (Oracle or OpenJDK) supports Java Flight Recorder?

Tags: java, oracle, jfr

Is there a way to check if a particular jdk (Oracle or OpenJDK) supports Java Flight Recorder ?
I have been trying to run my app on **OPEN JDK 8** as following

java -XX:StartFlightRecording

But this does not work on `OPEN JDK 8`. I get following error **Unrecognized VM option -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures**

but does not work

Comment: Related: [*Does openjdk 1.8.0_242 supports Java Flight Recorder?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61333887/642706)

Comment: Related: [Does OpenJDK 11 support Java Flight Recorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984944/does-openjdk-11-support-java-flight-recorder)

Answer (score 1):

One way to check if a JVM supports JFR is to do:

```
$ jdb
```

Open a second shell.

```
$ jcmd
```

Remember the pid of the jdb process and do:

```
$ jcmd <pid> help
```

If the JVM list diagnostic commands starting with JFR, it is supported. If the JDK lacks jcmd, JFR is not supported (unless it is a JRockit JVM in which case jcmd is called jrcmd and the command to look for is start_flightrecording).

Comment: Using `jcmd <pid> help` I get `java.io.IOException: no such process`, I assume it means that JFR is not supported ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'unlock the commercial features' as described here:
 
https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH176

The command should look like this:

```
java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=60s,filename=myrecording.jfr MyApp
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not work on OPEN JDK 8. I get following error Unrecognized VM option -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures

Comment: Outdated information. Oracle has open-sourced both Flight Recorder and Mission Control on the OpenJDK project. Available free-of-cost. See [JEP 328: Flight Recorder](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328) and [Mission Control project page](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/).