# Does OpenJDK 11 support Java Flight Recorder?

Tags: java, openjdk-11, jfr

Following [this post](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jmh/issues/106#issuecomment-459867456) :

> jfr is supported natively in openjdk 11

and it is confirmed by [the features list of OpenJDK 11](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/):

> 328: Flight Recorder

However, from [this DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/using-java-flight-recorder-with-openjdk-11-1), about using JFR-linked option `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`:

> OpenJDK doesn’t recognize this option

And when I try for ex. with Gradle: `./gradlew clean -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures"` I get

> Process command line: C:\Program
> Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe
> -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures (...)
>
> Unrecognized VM option 'UnlockCommercialFeatures'

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JFR was a commercial feature in Oracle Java up to Java 1.8 that needed to be specially enabled (using `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`).

With Java 11 and later it is no longer a commercial feature so you don't need this flag.

Actually the linked article states:

> **JFR Packaging Differences**
> Oracle JDK 11 emits a warning when using the `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` option, whereas OpenJDK doesn’t recognize this option and reports an error.

And the example below that the author shows doesn't use the `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures`.

Comment: No more error, thanks. A side question just in case: I run `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=30s,filename=my_recording.jfr -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=256" clean` and no .jfr file is created, what could be the cause ?

Comment: @Coli I think it is created - it is just not at the place where you are looking for it. When starting gradle this it the FlightRecorder-Option applies to the gradle daemon and the gradle daemon has its working directory somewhere like `~/.gradle/daemon/<gradleversion>`

Comment: Found it, thanks.